# Google cloud platform and Asterisk

Tags: google-cloud-platform, asterisk

Anyone had a working with Asterisk server on Google Cloud?

My Sip clients can't register, do you know if I need specific settings in SIP.conf file?

Answer (score 1):

This is a very vague question, and there are many variables at play.

That being said, it looks like running a VoIP service on their servers is against their terms and conditions.  Your stuff will most likely get shut down if they catch you.

If you still want to mess with it...

Please confirm that your local public IP address is allowed to connect to the Asterisk server (domain setting in sip.conf).
Please confirm that your user + pass are correct (sip.conf)
Please confirm that your IP address is allowed to connect on the necessary ports on your hosted Asterisk implimentation (i am guessing this is configured in the google cloud platform)

Comment: Do they really prohibit running VoIP applications on GCP? Where did you find that?

Comment: Bowler                                                                                                              i'm just using it for test scenarios . do google cloud platform use Nat?  it maybe the problem?

Comment: @fireplus the type of configuration that the network interfaces use on GCE have only one option which by default is ONE_TO_ONE_NAT. Is it possible to elaborate more on what type of error the clients are receiving? Did you open the required ports in the GCE firewall? You might also want to check Section 3.3 ("Restrictions") of the GCP Terms of Service described at https://cloud.google.com/terms/. If you have any concerns about compatibility between your project and the Terms of Service, I would encourage you contact the Cloud Platform Sales team at https://cloud.google.com/contact/.